# Motor phase loss due to fc or esc?

Tags: flight-controller, esc

When I plug DC input on esc, the fc won’t boot up, and the 5v output on board is gone.
I can hear a clear sound different from which one is losing phase, and also I tested the resistance of each phase and they are all around 20.9. But when I pull them in bf it’s acting like lost a phase.
I’m sure the fc is broken but for the motor phase loss, whose problem is it, the esc or the fc.

Comment: 5V output on which board? ESC or FC? Also, when you say "phase", are you referring to the individual motor phases/wires?